# Is there an equivalent function to isdate () in oracle

Tags: sql, string, oracle, datetime

```
CASE WHEN ISDATE(LTRIM(RTRIM(rard.thevalue))) = 1     
THEN CONVERT(smalldatetime, LTRIM(RTRIM(rard.thevalue)))
WHEN ISDATE(LTRIM(RTRIM(rard2.thevalue))) = 1
THEN CONVERT(smalldatetime, LTRIM(RTRIM(rard2.thevalue)))
ELSE CONVERT(smalldatetime, LTRIM(RTRIM(r.receiptdate)))
```

I have this syntax in SQL which has to get converted into oracle. The column "thevalue" has different formats in it ex: HH:MM , MM/DD/YYYY, HH:MM:SS etc. So isdate() function is checking whether its matching the date format and then pulling the data. I would need similar kind of function to check whether the columns value is matching date time format and then display as date.

Comment: Which Oracle version do you use?

Comment: Please edit your question and include information on the data types of  `rard.thevalue`, `rard2.thevalue`, and `r.receiptdate`, along with some example data for each. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The Oracle equivalent would be [`validate_conversion()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/VALIDATE_CONVERSION.html#GUID-DC485EEB-CB6D-42EF-97AA-4487884CB2CD).

However, unlike SQL Server, Oracle won't recognize varying formats. You need to explicitly specify the format that you want (unless your dates already are in the format configured by `nls_date_format`). Basically, you could test each possible format one after the other, and stop whenever one is recognized.

Since your purpose is to actually convert the string to a `date`, it would be simpler to use directly [`to_date()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TO_DATE.html#GUID-D226FA7C-F7AD-41A0-BB1D-BD8EF9440118), with the `on conversion error` clause.

Consider something like:

```
coalesce(
    to_date(thevalue default null on conversion error, 'MM/DD/YYYY'),
    to_date(thevalue default null on conversion error, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
    ...
)
```

Notes:

- the function happily ignores leading and trailing spaces, so there is no need to `trim()` beforehand
- this requires Oracle 12.2 or higher
- `isdate()` is not really safe in SQL Server; better use `try_convert()`, which basically behaves like Oracle's `to_date()` with `default null on conversion error`